# Solving a Simple SDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I am wondering, does, $F(X) = e^X$ a solution to the problem of

$dX = \mu dt + \sigma dW$?

My understanding of solving SDE is simply start with a guess solution, then expand using Ito's formula, if we can get back the SDE that is being asked, then we are done. But what exactly is the example below demonstrate?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have a clear understanding of what is going on. The example is simply an application of the Ito's Formula.

> **Ito's Formula.** Suppose that $X(\cdot)$ has a stochastic differential
> $$
> dX = Fdt+GdW \tag{1}
> $$
> for $F \in L^1(0,T)$, $G \in L^2(0,T)$. Assume $u:\mathbb{R} \times[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$,$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$,$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ exist and continuous. $$
> Z \overset{define}{=} u(X(t),t)
> $$
> Then $Z$ has the stochastic differential
> $$\begin{align}
> dZ &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dX + \frac12 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}G^2dt \\
> &= \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}F+\frac12 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}G^2\right)dt + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}GdW \tag{2}
> \end{align}
> $$

In your example, $F = \mu$, $G=\sigma$, and $Z =u(X(t),t)= e^X$. The partial derivatives are computed as
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 0, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=e^X=Z, \quad \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=e^X=Z
$$
Substitute into the equation (2), one gives
$$
\begin{equation}
dZ= \left(0+\mu Z+\frac12 \sigma^2Z\right)dt + \sigma ZdW = \left(\mu +\frac12 \sigma^2\right)Zdt + \sigma ZdW \tag{3}
\end{equation}
$$
If $Z$ is a solution, we should have
$$
\mu = \left(\mu +\frac12 \sigma^2\right)Z\quad \text{and}\quad \sigma = \sigma Z
$$

Comment: Do, if I compare (1) and (3), I got $F= \mu + 1/2 \sigma^2$, and also the other term for $G$. Do what getting these two terms the answer?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: "The answer is to substitute back to verify." What do I substitute to what?

Comment: Substitute your guessed solution back to the SDE.

Comment: You mean substitute $Z=e^X$ onto $dX=\mu dt + \sigma dW$?

Comment: Yes, like what you do for any DE.

Comment: But I don't know what is $\mu$ and $\sigma$

Comment: Can you please help me to write out the process, sorry just want to make sure this is I want had in mind

Comment: You are confusing yourself. The equation (3) contains $\mu$ and $\sigma$

Comment: Yes, (3) got $\mu, \sigma$, do I compare this with (1)? If so, then my answer is $F=\mu + 1/2 \sigma^2$?